# Update time display every minute, not just on create?

Tags: android

I want the activity time to update every minute, not just on create. This is the code I have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Atlantic/St_Helena");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
        String timez = String.format("Year "+"%02d" , c.get(Calendar.YEAR))

 // Display formattedDate value in TextView

        TextView time = new TextView(this);
        time.setText("Its"+timez+" PM"+"\n\n"+"Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning.");
        time.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        time.setTextSize(20);
        setContentView(time);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a runnable and a handler like this:

```
handler=new Handler();

new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
        timez = String.format("Year "+"%02d", c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        time.setText("Its"+timez+" PM"+"\n\n"+"Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning.");
        time.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        time.setTextSize(20);
        setContentView(time);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
    }
}.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i have so far

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                 }
            });
        }
},0,1000);
```

What i want to do is replace the ,0,1000); at the end with something like 60 minutes - current time.